# SQL - Query to identify the parentid in a hierarchy with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL azure database with a hierarchy of parents and i want to identify in the total hierarchy of the parents the parent id for each item that meets some conditions.

As an example this could be a great example

```
categoryId  parentId    Typeid
1           null         1
2           1            2
3           2            3
4           3            4
5           3            4
6           null         5
7           6            1
8           7            2
9           8            3
10          9            4
11          9            4
```

And I want to find for each categoryID the ParentId in the hierarchy that the type is 1 and if this category is the type 1 put the same category, in order to receive something like this.

```
categoryId  parentId     Typeid   ParentSearch
1           null         1        1
2           1            2        1
3           2            3        1
4           3            4        1
5           3            4        1
6           null         5        null
7           6            1        7
8           7            2        7
9           8            3        7
10          9            4        7
11          9            4        7
```

As you can see all the categories from 1 to 5 the parent with type 1 is the category 1
and for the categories from 6 to 11, the 6 need to be null and the rest the parent is 7.

It could be possible?
Maybe creating a path or something. i have done doing several left joins at leves and it is fine but i dont want to create 500leves in order to be sure that we never have 500 levels childs.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Which database do you use?  Could you please tag the question with it

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the logic is, accept that it looks like your trying to walk through each parent untill the parentId is null, in that case it is a 'root parent' (id 1 and 6). You're looking for a recursive function for that I believe. 11 > 9 > 8 >7 > 6

Comment: It is a SQL azure database. but and right im looking the root parent that has the condition typeid =1, for that reason the parents should be 1 and 7, instead of 1 and 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recursive CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) is your friend:

```
WITH parents AS
 (SELECT categoryid, parentid, typeid
       , CASE WHEN typeid = 1 THEN categoryid ELSE NULL END AS parentsearch
  FROM mytable
  WHERE parentid IS NULL
 UNION ALL
  SELECT c.categoryid, c.parentid, c.typeid
       , coalesce(p.parentsearch, CASE WHEN c.typeid = 1 THEN c.categoryid ELSE null END)
  FROM mytable AS c
  JOIN parents AS p ON c.parentid = p.categoryid)
SELECT * FROM parents ORDER BY categoryid;
```

```
categoryid  parentid    typeid      parentsearch
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------
1           (null)      1           1           
2           1           2           1           
3           2           3           1           
4           3           4           1           
5           3           4           1           
6           (null)      5           (null)      
7           6           1           7           
8           7           2           7           
9           8           3           7           
10          9           4           7           
11          9           4           7
```

[Sql Server db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c22a062102d4b25e478043988976c47).

Comment: @DanielObrOlm forgot to mention, you'll want an index on the `parentid` column if this table is of any decent size.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that uses a recursive CTE.
But this one seeds from the childs.

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT t.categoryId, t.parentId, t.typeId, 
    0 as lvl,
    t.categoryId as nextCategoryId,
    t.parentId as nextParentId,
    t.typeId as nextTypeId
    FROM CategoryRelations t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.categoryId, c.parentId, c.typeId, 
    c.lvl + 1, 
    t.categoryId,
    t.parentId,
    t.typeId
    FROM RCTE c
    JOIN CategoryRelations t ON t.categoryId = c.nextParentId
    WHERE c.typeId != 1
)
SELECT
 c.categoryId,
 c.parentId, 
 c.typeId,
 (case when c.nextTypeId = 1 then c.nextCategoryId end) as ParentSearch
FROM RCTE c
WHERE (c.nextTypeId = 1 or c.parentId is null)
ORDER BY categoryId;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/GBNZF12025)